# Selenium Chrome driver does not recognize certificates, but manual browsing works fine

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am encountering an issue with Selenium and Chrome where the browser does not recognize certificates when using the Selenium Chrome driver.
Strangely, when I manually open Google Chrome and visit the same websites, everything works fine.
Below is the code I'm using:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chromeOptions)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following result:

[image]

Could someone please help me understand what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using selenium wire You need to install the certificate in your local machine
You can also get the certificate by running the following command

```
python -m seleniumwire extractcert
```

or

```
python3 -m seleniumwire extractcert
```

You can also get the file from below link also jut copy paste it to a file and name it "ca.crt"

[Cert](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/master/seleniumwire/ca.crt)

Once you have the ".crt" file downloaded you have to import the certificate.
In MAC Open Keychain Access and them import items and them import the .crt file , then search for "Selenium Wire CA" cert , double click , expand the trust section and select Always trust, after this you should not see Not Secured  in chrome anymore

For windows
Launch MMC (mmc.exe) -> Choose File > Add/Remove Snap-ins -> Choose Certificates, then choose Add -> Choose My user account
-> Choose Add again and this time select Computer Account -> Move the new certificate from the Certificates-Current User -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities into Certificates (Local Computer) -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/sdn/articles/installing-the-trusted-root-certificate)